# How to disable print functionality in swf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, flash

I have to disable functionality of print on swf document.
In ASP.Net I have one iframe in to that I open the swf file which is in readonly mode,but I want to only restrict the print functionality of swf file.

Comment: So you don't want to display the iframe containing the SWF file during printing?

Comment: I don't want to print the swf file.